# How to auto add gems version in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to freeze the gems in Gemfile to prevent gems dependency conflict

I might have the following gems in my Gemfile.

After a period of time, my partner checkout the project and run **bundle install**, some gems might have higher version number

And it might some conflict among them.

Is there any tool can add fixed version number to the following gems with the currently workable gems.

```
 55 gem 'kaminari'
 56 gem 'rspec'
 57 gem 'awesome_print', require: 'ap'
 58 gem 'tinymce-rails'
 59 gem 'haml-rails'
 60 gem 'taps'
 61 gem 'analytics-ruby'
 62 gem 'bourbon'
 63 gem 'cancancan'
 64 gem 'rb-readline'
```

For example, if the gem 'kaminari''s version is 1.0 in my current project,
Then

Change `gem 'kaminari'` to `gem 'kaminari', '1.0'` in the Gemfile.

But there are too many gems in the Gemfile,

Is there any tool can do this for me ?

Comment: Do you not check in your `Gemfile.lock` to version control? This file locks the version of all your gems so anyone who runs `bundle install` in the project gets the same gem versions

Comment: Also, push Gemfile.lock, it will maintain version of gems, unless bundle is not updated. It will install the same version.

Answer (score 7):

You should check out the [Pessimize](https://github.com/joonty/pessimize) gem, which adds version numbers with to all gems in your Gemfile automatically.

Simply install the gem:

`gem install pessimize`

And run it:

`pessimize`

Comment: Linking to an external resource is helpful but please consider adding some detail to explain this answer further.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at gemfile.lock or run `bundle show` in the terminal to get a list of your app's gems and versions being used. However, this will also include gem dependencies. It looks like the gem [pessimize](https://github.com/joonty/pessimize) will help you out. It states it will:

> Add version numbers with the pessimistic constraint operator to all gems in your Gemfile

So you can install it and run it and it will add version numbers to your app, with the `~>` operator which only allows minor version bumps.